# How to pass array of object in POST API in NESTJS?

Tags: json, api, rest, post, nestjs

How can i pass array of object in POST API? I have achieved the simple request API but now i want an array of object for only one object in JSON.

Here is my DTO:

```
export class financialProposalDTO{

    @ApiProperty({ name: 'sponsors' })
    sponsors: string[];

    @ApiProperty({ name: 'totalCostOfExecution' })
    totalCostOfExecution: string;

    @ApiProperty({ name: 'equity' })
    equity: string;

    @ApiProperty({ name: 'debtOrLoan' })
    debtOrLoan: string;
}
```

Here is my Entity table:

```
@Table
export class FinancialProposal extends Model {

    @Column({
        type: DataType.ARRAY(DataType.STRING), isArray: true
    })
    sponsor: string[];

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
    })
    totalCostOfExecution: string;
    
    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
    })
    equity: string;

    @Column({
        type: DataType.STRING,
    })
    debtOrLoan: string;
}
```

Here is the controller:

```
    @Public()
    @Post('/:id/financialProposals')
    async submitFinancialProposal( @Param('id') applicationId, @Body() body) {
        await this.applicationService.submitFinancialProposal(applicationId, body);
        return SUCCESS
    }
```

Here is the Service:

```
 async submitFinancialProposal(applicationId, data: financialProposalDTO){
        return await this.financialRepository.create({ ...data, applicationId });
    }
```

I want to achieve this:

```
{
  "sponsor":[
    {
      "sponsorName": "abc",
      "legalStatus": "individual",
      "formationYear": "2022"
    },
    {
      "sponsorName": "test",
      "legalStatus": "legal",
      "formationYear": "2020"
    },
  ]
  "totalCostOfExecution": "test",
  "equity": "test",
  "debtOrLoan": "test"
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to be able to pass. You say you want an array of objects, but then you show an object that has one property that is an array while the rest are strings. Are you wanting an array of that entire object? i.e. `financialProposalDTO[]`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel No, I don't want array of entire object. I want only one object Sponsors as array and rest of them single. I want to achieve the attached JSON format when i hit this POST API in postman with following JSON body. Make sense of my question?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is then. That's completely possible to do out of the box. Are you having trouble documenting that through swagger, or sending the request in the first place?